# Search by slug in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named `homes`. Here is the simplified mapping of it:

```json
{
  "template": "homes",
  "index_patterns": "homes",
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "60s"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "status": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "fields": {
          "suggest": {
            "type": "search_as_you_type"
          },
          "search": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there is an `address` field which I query this way:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "sale"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "address": "406 - 533 Richmond St W"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that I need to be able to query with slugyfied version of the `address` field as well. For example, I need to query like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status": "sale"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "address": "406-533-richmond-st-w"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

So, instead of `406 - 533 Richmond St W` I need to query `406-533-richmond-st-w`. How can I do that? I was thinking of adding a new field `address_slug` which is the slugyfied version of `address` but I need it to be auto populated so I don't need to manually fill this field every time that I insert or update a document in the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a custom analyzer with the token filters below and another field for search that uses the custom analyzer, you can achieve this. Here is an example analyze result and output:

```
GET {index}/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "lowercase"
    },
    {
      "type": "pattern_replace",
      "pattern": """[^A-Za-z0-9]+""",
      "replacement": "-"
    }
  ],
  "text": "406 - 533 Richmond St W"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "406-533-richmond-st-w",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 23,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```